# How to get multiple row counts merged from mysql_fetch_rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to get the total number of product sales in each category, although the database structure being used doesn't really seem to lend itself to this.

I've gotten it to the point where I have the IDs of products (it's own  table)  in a category (another table) that have only been purchased (still another table). So looping through the category, I choose the IDs in the orders table and try to count the rows.  I end up with the item count per item, but any way I try to merge and count them up them doesn't work.

```
$SQL = "SELECT * from PRODUCTS WHERE CATEGORY LIKE '%-$thiscat-%' AND STATUS = 'Active' AND STOREITEM = 'Yes' AND ID IN ($item_ids)";
$result = mysql_query( $SQL ); 
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
   $sql_active_accounts = "SELECT count(ID) FROM ORDERS WHERE ITEM_NUMBER ='$row[ID]'";
   $res_active_accounts = mysql_query($sql_active_accounts);
   while($row_active_accounts = mysql_fetch_row($res_active_accounts)){  
       print_r($row_active_accounts); 
   }
};
```

An example that print_r gives for a specific category that only had 3 items sell, but some items sold more than once:

```
Array ( [0] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 3 ) Array ( [0] => 1 )
```

This is correct in that three items sold, sold those number of times.
And array_sum doesn't work on this. I can't seem to do anything to get those numbers to add up. I'm trying to count just specific rows and really don't care about the data in them for the final result.

I understand SQL calls within loops are a bad idea, but this is an admin area script that won't be run often.

Comment: I swear every *single* question where someone is using `mysql_query` has a gigantic [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Please **DO NOT USE** this antiquated interface because you will probably do it wrong and suffer severe consequences. It doesn't take long to learn to use placeholders in `mysqli` or PDO and it will save you a lot of trouble in the future if you do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$SQL = "SELECT * from PRODUCTS WHERE CATEGORY LIKE '%-$thiscat-%' AND STATUS =  'Active' AND STOREITEM = 'Yes' AND ID IN ($item_ids)";
$result = mysql_query( $SQL ); while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
$sql_active_accounts = "SELECT count(ID) FROM ORDERS WHERE ITEM_NUMBER ='$row[ID]'";
$res_active_accounts = mysql_query($sql_active_accounts);

$int_total = 0;
while($row_active_accounts = mysql_fetch_row($res_active_accounts) {

    foreach($row_active_accounts as $i)
        $int_total += $i;

}

// Use $int_total for total value
```

Some like this should do the trick for your if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$query = mysql_query("select distinct(pgroup) from test") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo $row['pgroup']."=>";       
    $query1="SELECT count(*),pname FROM `test` where pgroup='$row[pgroup]' group by pname ";
    $result1=mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
    $rows1=mysql_num_rows($result1);
    while($row_sub=mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
        $query2 = "select * from test where pname = '".$row_sub['pname']."'";
        $res2=mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error().'errror here');
        $row2 = mysql_num_rows($res2);
        echo $row_sub['pname']."=".$row2."<br/>";       
    }
}
```